# Почему SQL Server не вызывает Select?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть вот такой курсор:

```
Declare cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table100500'

open cur
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @ColumnName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIn
        SELECT @ColumnName
        Declare @CurrentCMD NVARCHAR(500)=REPLACE(@CMD,'#ColumnName#',@ColumnName)
        Exec sp_executesql  @CurrentCMD
        FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @ColumnName
    END
```

Который идет и выполняет обновления по колонкам.

Так вот, что бы наблюдать за прогрессом я сделал себе SELECT @ColumnName.

Однако, почему-то SQL Server его не вызывает, хотя если заглянуть в таблицу над которой я произвожу данные манипуляции, то я вижу, что работу он уже какую-то сделал.

Почему SQL Server не вызывает Select?

Comment: приведите полный скрипт выполнения, а то не понятно что такое @ColumnName и что вы хотите от обычного select

Comment: @Konst чуть подправил.

Comment: посмотрите что у вас @CurrentCMD содержит перед вызовом exec и сразу всё поймёте

Comment: @Konst там все четко. Я проверял. Если косяк был там, тогда бы скрипт обвалился. Ну и вопрос не в этом. Вопрос в том, почему SELECT ColumnName на каждую итерацию выборку не делает...

Comment: сделайте PRINT @ColumnName

Comment: @Konst RAISERROR (@ColumnName, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT  помог. Похоже там тоже какая-то буферизация и результат не сразу возвращается...

Comment: Select выполняется, просто результат отправляется клиенту не сразу, а когда данных наберётся хотя бы на один пакет, или когда запрос завершён и в пакет больше нечего положить.

Comment: По поводу буферизации и пакетов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/949545/184217 - может кому интересно будет